# Prove or disprove wether the sentence $\exists x\forall y Q(x,y)\to \forall y\exists x Q(x,y)$ is logically true

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

I got stuck at this problem for some hours:

> Determine whether the first-order sentence $\exists x\forall y Q(x,y)\to \forall y\exists x Q(x,y)$ is logically true,
>   where $Q$ is a 2-ary predicate symbol.
>
> If the sentence is logically true then prove it. And if the sentence is false then find a model $\mathcal{M}$ in which the sentence is false, that is, find a model $\mathcal{M}$ in which $$\mathcal{M}\nvDash\exists x\forall y Q(x,y)\to \forall y\exists x Q(x,y)$$

---

I tried the model $M=<\mathbb{N}; Q>$ in which $Q^M=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}^2| x^2=y\}$, and it doesn't worked.

I tried several other models and it doesn't worked too.

Thanks for any hint/help.

Comment: I think it is true in any interpretation.

Comment: user121270 is right. Are you sure your sentence has $\rightarrow$ rather than $\leftrightarrow$? (If so, I will undelete my answer to the wrong question $\ddot{\smile}$.)

Comment: I've edited the question since I've firstly thought that the sentence is false for some model.

Comment: [Here](http://s17.postimg.org/c4jvuji5r/proofnd.jpg)'s a proof in natural deduction.

Comment: With $\rightarrow$, it's true, so you should work on proving it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've managed to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work out the tableau of the negation of your sentence:

> 1. $\neg\big(\exists x\forall yQxy\to\forall y\exists xQxy\big)$
> 2. $\exists x\forall yQxy$ (1)
> 3. $\neg\forall y\exists xQxy$ (1)
> 4. $\forall y Qay$ (2)
> 5. $\exists y\neg\exists xQxy$ (3)
> 6. $\neg\exists xQxb$ (5)
> 7. $\forall x\neg Qxb$ (6)
> 8. $\neg Qab$ (7)
> 9. $Qab$ (4)
> 10. $\bot$

The tableau of the negation of the sentence closes, therefore it is valid:
$$\vDash\exists x\forall yQxy\to\forall y\exists xQxy$$